# Using flow in react redux project

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype

I'm getting some annoying issues while trying to apply type to connect function. I'm not sure, the flow is implemented correctly. I applied the same implementation to 2 separate JS files, one is okay, but the other one keeps raising errors like this

```
1. all branches are incompatible: Either  null [1] is incompatible with  function type [2]. Or  null [1] is incompatible with  function type [3].Flow(InferError)

2. a call signature declaring the expected parameter / return type is missing in  `ReduxDispatchProps` [1] but exists in  function type [2] in the return value.Flow(InferError)
```

btw, Here is my implementation.

```
interface ReactProps {
  user?: User;
  asset?: Asset;
  autoUpdate?: boolean;
  std_time?: number;
  handleOpenModalUpdateStandardTime?: (standardTime: StandardTime) => void;
}

interface ReduxStateProps {}

interface ReduxDispatchProps {
  updateEntityStandardTime: UpdateEntityStandardTimeHandler;
}

interface IProps extends ReduxStateProps, ReactProps, ReduxDispatchProps {}

class ComponentA extends Component<IProps,{}> {}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch): ReduxDispatchProps => {
  return {
    updateEntityStandardTime: (payload: StandardTime, callback: ?Callback) =>
      dispatch(updateEntityStandardTimeRequest(payload, callback)),
  };
};

export default connect<IProps, ReactProps, _, _, _, _>(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ComponentA);
```

Looking forward to help from you guys!

Comment: FWIW, at this would point we would specifically recommend using TypeScript instead of Flow. Flow has a very small community, there are few packages with Flow types, and TS has basically won the war. Redux Toolkit is written in TypeScript, and the Redux core is being converted to TS.  That's not to say you _can't_ use Redux with Flow, just that you're going against the tide here.

Comment: can you also show definition of `UpdateEntityStandardTimeHandler`?